# getting xhtml custom attributes from jquery in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, attributes

i got some **li** elements with a custome attribute "type".

whe i try in jquery to get the value of this attribute width jquery like so:

```
$("li", $list).each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr("type"));
 });
```

i only get the values in firefox but not in IE 7-8

any solutions?

Comment: var $list = $("#manage_menu");

#manage_menu = the ul element.

enyway if i"m trying to get lets say the ID it works fine

Comment: IE may be error'ing on the call to `console.log()`, which is a firebug construct. Change it to `alert()` and post an update.

Comment: the cosnole.log is used in IE8 wich has a console so its fine:)

Answer (score 3):

`type` is a deprecated attribute for `ul`, `ol`, and `li` elements that IE still supports, along with `start`, `value` and `compact`. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#adef-type-OL.

Prefix your custom attributes with "`data-`". So you'd do instead:

```
<ul>
    <li data-type="foo">Item</li>
    <li data-type="bar">Item</li>
</ul>
```

and then:

```
$('li').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('data-type'));
})
```

Then there won't be any reserved attribute name clashes in the future, with any browser.

See [Custom Attributes in HTML 5](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/customattributes.shtml) for more info.